# Поиск по первым буквам слова

Tags: javascript, foreach, search

Пишу поиск для аудиоплеера. Возникла проблема: почему-то пишет что `allForSearch is not defined`

```
var songs = [{
   url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Redfoo_-_New_Thang.mp3',
   artist: {
       name: 'Redfoo',
       song: 'New Thang'
   }
},
{ 
   url: 'http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpoc6cHNDP1r0jthjo1.mp3',
   artist: {
            name: 'Hugo',
            song: '99 Problems'
        }
    }
];

search = () => {
  const {
    songs
  } = this.state;
  var input = this.textInput.value;
  songs.forEach(function(item) {
    var names = item.artist.name,
      song = item.artist.song,
      allForSearch = names.concat(song);
  });

  function init() {
    let template = `<td><a href=#>%name</a></td>`,
      search = document.querySelector('.search'),
      tr = document.querySelector('.mess-hide'),
      render = a => tr.innerHTML = a.map(e => template.replace('%name', e)).join(`\n`);

    search.addEventListener('.search', function(e) {
      let value = input.toLowerCase();

      render(allForSearch.filter(e => e.toLowerCase().startsWith(value)));
    });
    render(allForSearch);
  }
}



<table className="table">
  <tr className="mess-hide">

  </tr>
</table>
```

Немного объясню: `songs` массив объектов. С помощью `forEach` я копирую все названия и имена в другой массив для того что бы осуществлять поиск. Но почему-то с `allForSearch` возникают проблемы. Почему так может быть?

Comment: также советую прочитать какой-либо стайлгайд ( пример: https://standardjs.com/rules.html ) и придерживаться его. Это повысит читаемость кода, что упростит жизнь вам и вашим коллегам

Answer (score 0):

`allForSearch` объявляется внутри функции, переданной в `songs.forEach`

```
songs.forEach(function(item) {
  var names = item.artist.name,
    song = item.artist.song,
    allForSearch = names.concat(song);
});
```

Объявите `var allForSearch` глобально, наряду с `var songs = []`, либо внутри блока `search = () => {`

Comment: Я вынес `allForSearch` в `search` тогда `names` и `song` is not defined.

Comment: @МаксимБуяков не нужно выносить всю строку `allForSearch = names.concat(song);`. Достаточно прописать `var allForSearch;` сразу после `search = () => {`, а внутри `forEach` всё так и оставить, кроме запятой после `song = item.artist.song,`, её лучше бы заменить на `;`